# php shell_exec bash.exe does not working in Window XP IIS

Tags: php, bash

generatedb.php

```
 <?php
if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') {
    echo 'This is a server using Windows!';
    $output = shell_exec("C:\\cygwin\\bin\\bash.exe --login -c C:\\cygwin\\bin\\mysql2sqlite.sh -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -pApacheah64 db_shuttlebus tbl_driver tbl_location tbl_rate tbl_route tbl_routeid tbl_vehicle | C:\\cygwin\\sqlite3.exe  C:\\Inetpub\\wwwroot\\BusTicket\\exportdatabase\\database.sqlite");
    echo "<pre>".$output."</pre>";
} else {
    echo 'This is a server not using Windows!';
    $output = shell_exec("bash mysql2sqlite.sh -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -pApacheah64 db_shuttlebus tbl_driver tbl_location tbl_rate tbl_route tbl_routeid tbl_vehicle | sqlite3  /var/www/BusTicket/exportdatabase/database.sqlite");
    echo "<pre>".$output."</pre>";
}

?>
```

this is the error out the output

```
Warning: shell_exec(): Unable to execute 'C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --login -c
C:\cygwin\bin\mysql2sqlite.sh -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -pApacheah64 db_shuttlebus tbl_driver  
tbl_location tbl_rate tbl_route tbl_routeid tbl_vehicle | C:\cygwin\sqlite3.exe 
C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\BusTicket\exportdatabase\database.sqlite' in   
C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\BusTicket\exportdatabase\generatedb.php on line 4
```

if i manually open cmmand promt and run the command are working fine, but when in PHP then it is can't work. why?

i have checked `php.ini` safe mode are off and disable_functions = are blank.

and this is my phpinfo.php

[image]

this is i m using cmd.exe to run the command, it is working

[image]

Comment: Try reading the error messages next time. As states "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\BusTicket\exportdatabase\generatedb.php on line 4" Although, in your question you never mentioned anything about generatedb.php, so I would suggest you take a look at that file and see what may be happening there.  If you still don't know, try posting "line 4" and we may be able to help you.

Comment: @user2840647 code updated, please have a look

Comment: can you also post the line which contains "disable_functions = ..." in php.ini, please.

Comment: Since you said you are on an IIS Server, take a look at this link. [php_shell_exec](http://tech.trailmax.info/2012/12/php-warning-shell_exec-unable-to-execute-on-iis-7/) Hope this helps!

Comment: sorry, winxp IIS is 5.1 only

Comment: did you try it anyway?

Comment: there is no way to change the FastCGI setting, do u know how to change the FastCGI setting is IIS 5.1?

Comment: hate to ask, but is it possible that this is a permission issue? maybe the user php runs under (prolly your webserver user) does not have access to run C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe. id start there

Comment: @loushou, how to set php permission?

Comment: @ChinYe What about open_basedir? Possibly you don't have a C:\cygwin\bin in open_basedir allowed path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing IIS, there are probably multiple possible explanations. Here's one I found on http://www.php.net/shell_exec

> Got the error "Unable to execute..." when trying to run an external program with shell_exec under Windows XP, IIS 5, php 4.3.7  Solved by giving the IIS user (IUSR_...) execution privileges on the system file %systemroot%\system32\cmd.exe  This should be used carefully because may represent a server's security hole.

HTH.